# How to implement http-only cookie auth from aws hosted backend to locally hosted frontend?

Tags: reactjs, axios, setcookie, httpcookie, cookie-httponly

When your backend is deployed to aws and you have to develop http cookie authentication to a locally hosted reactjs frontend how do you implement it?

The issue is..

When I call the login API endpoint it's supposed to set a http-only cookie to my browser but it doesn't.

I've mentioned my axios intecepter below incase if it's the issue. If you can suggest me a solution that would be great.

ps : the backend doesn't have a issue, When i call the login endpoint with postman. relevant cookies are setting automatically

```js
export const axiosHttp = axios.create({
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  withCredentials: true,
});

axiosHttp.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => response,
  async (error) => {
    const prevRequest = error?.config;
    if (error.response.status === 401 && !prevRequest?.sent) {
      prevRequest.sent = true;
      const res = await refreshToken();
      console.log(res);
      return axiosHttp(prevRequest);
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

Comment: What are you using in the backend, it's not related to AWS, just set http-only on your backend technology.

Comment: @quyentho it's a express backend. i dont think it's a backend issue since the cookies works as it suppose to work when i test the apis on postman but with the frontend (locally hosted) it wont work.

Comment: How can you be sure it's not working on the frontend? Have you checked the developer tools (devtools)?  If you can, could you edit your question to include the response containing the HttpOnly cookie when you make the request using Postman?